# how to use onFocusChange if i have only 1 edittext?

Tags: java, android

i try to make action when i lost focus on edittext or click in blankspace in layout but it wont work if i have 1 edittext.

my code in Main.java

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
});
```

this is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context="com.example.pollk.Main" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your RelativeLayout contains other kind of Views just set the following attributes to them to make them focusable:

> ```
> android:focusable="true"
> android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
> ```

2. Add an `OnClickListener` to your RelativeLayout, so you can receive an click event when click in blankspace.

Answer (score 0):

add `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in your xml file

Answer (score 0):

i have question. So i try this code.

```
        edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!hasFocus){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }});


    final RelativeLayout layout1=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.hidebg);
    layout1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }   
    });
```

it's work for me but this is a right solution? because i declare onclick function but i don't use it.